# Icon size help WINAPI only showing small c

Tags: c, winapi, icons, size

Hi there just a quick question I hope someone can help me with I am loading a logo onto my dialog application into a static picture holder using the .rc file and adding this code.

```
ICON IDI_MYICON,IDC_STATIC_IMAGE,120,154,21,20
```

However my problem is this will only display a 64x64 image max and the banner I have loaded is 242x74 in size am I using the wrong method in using ICON? I did try bitmap but didnt work either.

Thanks

Comment: It's been ages since I've dealt with .rc files, so maybe there's something new I don't know about, but according to this your statement is out of whack.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `21,20` in your statement is the width and height of the icon control in [dialog units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb847924.aspx).  Dialog units vary depending on things like screen DPI and the font selected.  There are typically 2-4 pixels per dialog unit.  You've basically given the icon something on the order of 64x64 to display in.

To get the icon control sized pixel-perfectly, you can to resize it dynamically, e.g., during `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Also, I'm not sure which method the dialog box code uses to load the icon--some (like LoadIcon) restrict the size to a "standard" size which others (like LoadImage) do not.

Comment: cheers that sorted it just changing the numbers at the end to 242x74 thanks.